# How does Qt find widget instances?

Tags: c++, qt

*At the first, Qt isn't my primary framework as well as C++ isn't my primary language, so my question may be very easy but it's unclear for me from tutorials.*

There is a simple sample in official tutorial:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);

 QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
 button.show();

 return app.exec();
}
```

But they don't explain how `button` links with `app` to it could be shown and wait events. I can imagine there is a some singleton and `button`, and `app` find each other via that singleton or there is a some preprocessor that finds widget instances and automatically links it with `app` instance. But I want to know real situation. How are they linked together?

**P.S.** *I am sure someone asked a similar question already but I couldn't find. If you know any duplicate of my question, specify it, pls, I will delete my topic then.*

Comment: I think your guess is correct. Other UI libraries like FLTK work similarly btw.

Comment: @nada, I mean I want to know surely how it works in Qt. There is a lot of possible scenarios for UI frameworks to find and build widget tree.

Comment: It's kinda open source, why not simply have  a look at QApplication in detail then?

Comment: Please be also advised, that there are other UI libraries and Qt has tons of problems.

Comment: @nada, I am noobie in C++) It's still hard for me to read C++ code free

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is almost correct despite the fact that the "singleton" is the `QApplication` itself.

By reading the [`QApplication`'s documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#details), you can see that only one `QApplication` object has to exist.
According to the documentation again:

> "It handles widget specific initialization, finalization."

Then to answer your question, I know that there exists a global pointer to the `QApplication` instance that you can access via [`qApp`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp).
I'm pretty sure that this is what it is used by any `QWidget` to find the `QApplication` object.

Comment: @Шах Thing about qApp is true. `qApplication` object only handles some dispatched events and application wide properties, creation of `QObjects` included. E.g., command-line arguments, but that's described in documents as well. There is also a `QCoreApplication`, which is meant for non-GUI applications.There is some internal dispatcher which is not exposed in API.  Each `QObject`, widgets included, is part of global event dispatcher ,  parts of which are built by MOC utility when it parses source code.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, thank you, consluding, a skeleton of widget tree and event dispatching logic are built by pre-processor and globally available pointer to `QApplication` instance that is used by `QObject` children to add itself to the widget tree.

Comment: @Шах Not exactly. In fact `qApp` refers to a `QApplication` object. But it is for GUI applications (as mentioned in the doc too) so `QWidget` can use it. But for any `QObject`, not necessarily a `QWidget`, the event system is bring up by `QCoreApplication` for which a lot of things are handled by the meta object compiler and others that are just not exposed.

Comment: @Fareanor, yeah, sorry, it was a mistake. `QWidget`, of course.

Comment: @Fareanor can we consider it to be a mediator pattern, but hidden from end-user?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, I am a noobie in Qt, of course, but as I get objects interacts with `QApplication` only without direct links but not btw themself. Signals and slots are processed by pre-processor, so it can't be called a mediator pattern, imho (only if to consider a pre-processor as a part of a mediator pattern too).

Comment: @Шах that's separate thing, those macros actually call method connect() and it's part of subscription process, a dispatcher of sorts.  links between signal and slot are dynamic, not static. Signals are not necessary events, if they are direct, they  act like a function call, by a pointer.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie,  yap, I mean that it can't be called a mediator pattern cuz there aren't shadow interacts between object but `QApplication` instance. I can miss, so I will be glad if someone will explain why I am not right.

Comment: @Шах I consider QApplication itself being a mediator, because it doesn't implement directly what it is responsible for. It is a shadow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199361/discussion-between--and-swift-friday-pie).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I think we can say so. As `Q_OBJECT` initiates the creation of meta objects via the meta object compiler that are not supposed to be opened/modified by the user and thus allowing to use features like signals-slots mechanisms, `qobject_cast`... The generated moc files are kind of encapsulating mediators that will be compiled alongside the user's code, yes.